# Python/Selenium - Print text of an element before a character

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to print the name only from a list of bing search results. I can grab the whole title but just need the name befor the "-".

link: [https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3alinkedin.com%2fin%2f+and+%22mortgage%22+and+%22utah%22+and++%22provo%22&qs=HS&sc=8-0&cvid=9A3F034F845B491F890E6D02161C755C&sp=1&first=100&FORM=PERE4](https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F%20and%20%22mortgage%22%20and%20%22utah%22%20and%20%20%22provo%22&qs=HS&sc=8-0&cvid=9A3F034F845B491F890E6D02161C755C&sp=1&first=100&FORM=PERE4)

```
titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('b_algo')
name = [div.find_element_by_tag_name('h2 > a').get_attribute('innerHTML') for div in titles]

print(name)
```

I would like the output to be:
Tom Powell,
Marty Johnson,
Matt Gardner,
etc..

Comment: I'm trying to get all the names on the results page so that throws an error

Comment: what kind of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab everything before the - and strip the last space.

```
titles=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "b_algo")))
name = [div.find_element_by_tag_name('h2 > a').get_attribute('innerHTML').split('-')[0].strip() for div in titles]
```

Outputs

```
['Lauren Kearl',
 'Tennison Hunter',
 'Doug Blackhurst',
 'Doug Daniels',
 'Connor Hoiland',
 'Drew Dunham',
 'Peter Skaggs',
 'Lindsey Huish',
 'Rachel Hernandez',
 'Joseph Vore']
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```